# Read the excel file in the home directory using pandas based on the timeframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to see the difference/variance between two files in my script. but i am strucking at here;
for example i will upload the file using flask framework.

File Number 1 uploaded at 3:00 PM

File Number 2 uploaded at 2:50 PM

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel (r'Path where the Excel file is stored\File Number1.xlsx')
print (df)
```

how do I write the code to read the previousfile accroding to the timeframe
example I want to see the previousfile, obviously 2.50 PM (File Number2)

```
df1 = pd.read_excel ()
print (df1)
```

Comment: I'm very confused as to what the problem is here. Does file 2 get replaced by file 1 at 3pm?

Comment: Thanks for responding. For instance if I print(df) the File number 1 (3.00 PM) data will be displayed. how do I print (df1), which will read the file path and goes to the previous file not the currentone.

Comment: df as you have it written only contains File 1 because you have given it the path directly to File 1. if you want the second file you need to do `df1 = pd.read_excel (r'Path where the Excel file is stored\File Number2.xlsx')`

Comment: OK. I have a file path and stored 3 excel files file1, file2, file3. if i want to read the file1 and print it means, I can write the code df = pd.read_excel ('File1.xlsx') and print (df), how about if i want to read the file df1=pd.read_excel() not mentioning here the name file2, instead i want to write file1-1 (which means go back the file which stored in the order of file path and print it)

Comment: Im not even sure what youre asking

Answer (score 0):

You can get the file names from that path and sort it by modification time and print the last two files.

```
from pathlib import Path

fnames = Path("Path/of/xlsx files").glob("*.xlsx")
fnames_with_modtime = [(x, x.stat().st_mtime) for x in fnames]
#sort by modification time

fnames_with_modtime.sort(key = lambda x: x[1])

#last modified two files
file1, _ = fnames_with_modtime[-1]
file2, _ = fnames_with_modtime[-2]

df1 = pd.read_excel(file1)
df2 = pd.read_excel(file2)
print(df1)
print(df2)
```